# What things we should avoid in small screen, low bandwidth supported devices compare to big screen , high bandwidth supported devices?

Tags: css, xhtml, mobile-website

Mobile has low speed , internet subscription plans of mobile companies are "data upload/download based"

so bandwidth is the key in mobile site.

So what things we should avoid if me are making different css for mobiles or making different site for mobile.

some things i know to make mobile version of site quick to browse

- Flash
- silverlight
- much use of javascript/jquery
- fixed width width and height
- Big banner images

etc

Answer (score 2):

Just make it possible for users to visit your site with [`links`](http://www.jikos.cz/~mikulas/links/) (or any other text web browser), and you'll be 90% there.

If you do that, you can create a [simple separated CSS file](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/pocket/) that doesn't have most of the images and has friendlier font sizes.

You might want to have shorter/smaller pages, with links to get more info only on request, to save bandwidth.

Other than that, use common sense.